# How do I mock mailchimp_transactional in jest

Tags: unit-testing, npm, jestjs, mailchimp

I'm trying to figure out how to correctly mock the `@mailchimp/mailchimp_transactional` npm module in my tests.

I'm getting caught up in how it shows to import mailchimp from the documentation, with an immediate call to the constructor with the API key

```
const mailchimp = require('@mailchimp/mailchimp_transactional')(API_KEY);
```

According to the Jest documentation, I'd normally mock it with something like

```
jest.mock('@mailchimp/mailchimp_transactional');
```

But I'm not sure how to then create the instance with a fake API key? I keep getting an undefined result from trying to call the mocked version of `mailchimp`. Would I need to mock a `constructor()` function as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be something like this:

```
jest.mock(
  '@mailchimp/mailchimp_transactional',
  () => API_KEY => ({ object that mocks mailchimp })
);
```